# Can't remove hidden characters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting, copy-paste, ascii

I'm trying to make a simple tool for my job where I can decline job listings for a specific reason simply by checking their boxes and then copying and pasting the final cell where it will compile all the reasons into a formatted response.

[image: The spreadsheet]

Hopefully the way the spread sheet works is relatively clear.  I use a lot of `CHAR(10)`'s in this for formatting.  all the cells in the `N:N` column are essentially formatted like `=A1 &CHAR(10) &CHAR(10)` to add spacing between everything.

The main problem is when I copy and paste the text from the final cell, I end up with *ROWS* of empty line breaks.  I'm really not sure how this happens. I've tried the `TRIM()`, `SUBSTITUTE()`, and `CONCATENATE()` commands, removing the merged cells and the text wrapping, changing the cell formatting, and even removing a lot of the `CHAR(10)`'s (but not all) from the cell, but it still happens.  I even remade this sheet in Google Sheets and it STILL did it.

[image: The pasted blank space]

What am I missing here??

**Edit:** These are the changes I attempted from @cybernetic.nomad
it still doesn't seem to work properly.  Even when I copy the "filler" version, I get similar excess space like in the picture above.

I changed the formatting here just so you could see how I wrote each formula.

[First edit attempt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siHDy.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider using a placeholder character (or string) and once all the work is done, search and replace that character or string with char(10)

Comment: Replace all blank?

Comment: I need to better understand the structure of the grey "Merged Response" block you are copying from.  It covers P4:U46.  Is this merged to be a single "cell" or is it a 6 x 45 range of cells?  You may be copying and then pasting a lot of cell breaks into your text document in the form of carriage returns.

Comment: @MaxR The "Merged Response" block is a large merged cell, not individual cells.  I've actually tried unmerging and unwrapping this cell and copying from the single original cell and it still comes up with the blank space.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I attempted this but it didn't seem to work.  Even with the `CHAR(10)`'s totally removed and replaced with `"filler"` and then using the `SUBSTITUTE()` formula to replace it, it still seemed to have a large amount of space after the text.  I even typed the `TRIM()` formula on every relevant cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem WAS the merged cells.  I tried copying from them while unmerged again and it worked this time.  I'm not sure how I made this mistake last time.
My solution now was to make a button macro to copy from a separate cell where the text can be formatted correctly in an single unmerged cell, and now the big block of text is just for looks.

Comment: As a general rule, I would avoid merged cells wherever possible.  They are a way to "pretty up" a spreadsheet but they complicate our logic in really un-intuitive ways.  There are two things in Excel that I have essentially "sworn off" and won't do any more...  Merged cells, and conditional formatting logic based on formulas embedded in the conditional format.  I will always re-work the problem in a different way than resort to those.